# Spring Rest and Angular JS in one Project

Tags: angularjs, spring, tomcat, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I am trying to create a spring boot Multi-module Restful web service.
My plan is to use Angular JS and HTML pages to consume this web service along with a mobile app.

I am confused in how can I get the landing page when the tomcat starts if it's a Spring boot RestController.

I was thinking to add HTML pages in apache and RestFul Webservice in tomcat.

Is there any best solution so that I can use Webservice and Html in one tomcat

Comment: Have you look at Jhipster ? https://jhipster.github.io/ It scaffolds you a Spring Boot+AngularJS working app

Comment: @BiAiB ok, will go through the document

Answer (score 1):

You can serve your static content from spring-boot, so you do not need to additionally configure tomcat.

[spring-boot serving static content](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot)

Answer (score 1):

When it comes down to it, an AngularJS application consists of a bunch of HTML and JS files. Since those are simply static files, you can serve those files with Spring Boot. Here's a minimalistic example:

Spring boot application runner:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

A sample REST controller:

```
@RestController
public class MyRestController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/api")
    public String getSomething() {
        return "something";
    }
}
```

An index.html which bootstraps the angular app:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="/path/to/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="myangularapp.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="myAngularApp"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Where `index.html` and `myangularapp.js` are both located in `/resources/public` (assuming a Maven project structure)

When running the spring boot application the Angular app is accessible on http://localhost:8080/index.html 
The REST interface is accessible on http://localhost:8080/api